# Run test-case in case of failure step in unit test python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a testSuite in Python with several test cases using unit test framework. I am using import unit test for that

If a test step in test case fails, test case goes to teardown class. I would like to continue rest of the test case even if one test case fails.

The default behaviour of a unit test: If any test step fails, it goes to tear down class and end the test case.

Test step: I mean assert equal and like this inbuilt proc which defines whether it is a failure or pass

Comment: It always continues with the other tests. I don't know why you're experiencing the different.

Comment: Can you provide your tests code please? It'll make your question easier to answer

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your question, because I've always had my tests continue even when tests fail. I've never had issues with this. Considering there are several answers already, maybe I am missing a key piece I'm not understanding? Unless you are referring to multiple asserts in a single test method?

Answer (score 6):

Considering you have something like this:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)
        self.assertEqual(1, 3)
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

The first assert will fail and the following ones are not going to run but the test will end and self.tearDown method will be called instead.

When you assert you mean that condition is forcefully true or there is no meaning in continuing. You mean something like: "If one is not equal two then the life doesn't make sense anymore..." :)

That is the case most of the times. You wouldn't want to check the result body of a rest API if the result code is not the expected, for example.

You shall test all the equalities in one step to assure they are all going to be checked. You can group them as a tuple, for example:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        self.assertEqual((1, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1))
```

then you'll get an output like this:

```
AssertionError: Tuples differ: (1, 1, 1) != (2, 3, 1)

First differing element 0:
1
2

- (1, 1, 1)
?  ^  ^

+ (2, 3, 1)
?  ^  ^
```

From the python documentation:

> assertEqual(first, second, msg=None) 
>   Test that first and second are equal. If the values do not compare equal,
>   ***the test will fail***.
>
> In addition, if first and second are the exact same type and one of
>   list, tuple, dict, set, frozenset or str or any type that a subclass
>   registers with addTypeEqualityFunc() ***the type-specific equality
>   function will be called in order to generate a more useful default
>   error message*** (see also the list of type-specific methods).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual

[EDIT] -- after some clarification on this question comments itself but without a code example yet.

Considering you have something different, like this:

```
class TestBar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rest_api_foo(self):
        r = request("http://dummyurl")
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(r.text, "hello world")
```

You could do many (hacky) things like counting the failures instead of asserting and asserting the counter value at the end:

```
class TestBar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rest_api_foo(self):
        r = request("http://dummyurl")
        errors = (r.status_code != 200)
        errors += (r.text != "hello world")
        self.assertEqual(errors, 0)
```

Or create a helper function to assert, log, count and swallow the exception and then assert the counter at the end. There are many possibilities.

However, in general, the best (simplest, clear, boring as it should be) way would be the one already suggested in the comments:

```
class TestBar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rest_api_status_code_foo(self):
        r = request("http://dummyurl")
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)

    def test_rest_api_text_foo(self):
        r = request("http://dummyurl")
        self.assertEqual(r.text, "hello world")
```

Note that, in this specific example, a single test case would be better.

Anyway, that will give you separated error messages while keeping the code simple and easy to maintain.

If your problem, otherwise, is because the tearDown method is being called after each test case then you can use tearDownClass for cleanup instead (python3 or from unittest2).

I'm sure I have not covered all possibilities for your actual question here but maybe that was useful to show how many possibilities are for your open question. So, please, clarify your question.

Comment: I got ur point but while writing test cases there are number of test steps. Sometimes we donot want to stop at a failed step but instead we want the test to continue and printing the failed message.

Comment: That means you're testing multiple things in one test.  Don't do this.  In one test, test up to the first failure point to make sure it's working.  In another test, run the same setup, but don't check for that failure, (another test is taking care of that), check for the next failure instead.  And so on.  This could also be evidence that the function you're testing is too large.

Comment: If that is the case Nitesh it is like Adam has already answered: just split the test case in many steps. Furthermore, If I didn't get your point then please clarify your question adding examples as has been already asked. It seems like Adam Barnes should be accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems like Adam Barnes' comment should be the accepted answer, now that Nitesh added some clarification to the question in these comments.

Comment: Although it doesn't do what the question asks (which is unclear anyway), Adam Barnes' comment is the best approach, and that's what should be done for best practice

Answer (score 2):

How about `subTest`?

```
import unittest


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        with self.subTest('Failed'):
            self.assertEqual(5, 2 + 2)

        with self.subTest('Passed'):
            self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

olivecode's example will looks like this:

```
class TestBar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rest_api_foo(self):
        r = request("http://dummyurl")

        with self.subTest('Test status code'):
            self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)

        with self.subTest('Test text'):
            self.assertEqual(r.text, "hello world")
```

Comment: That is really interesting depending on your case. For the url request test, specifically, I'd keep it simple in one test case and just don't check the text if the code is wrong. Of course that is a valid as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!  There isn't a built-in way to continue when an `assert*` helper fails in `unittest` (or [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), a common Python testing framework).

The most idiomatic way to achieve the same effect is to use compare a dict or tuple of values all at once.

```
class TestBar(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rest_api_foo(self):
        r = request("http://dummyurl")

        # using a tuple
        # `assertEqual` works as well, `assertTupleEqual` specifically
        # highlights which elements that are different
        self.assertTupleEqual(
            (200, "hello world"),
            (r.status_code, r.text),
        )

        # using a dict
        # `assertEqual` works as well, `assertDictEqual` specifically
        # highlights which elements that are different
        self.assertDictEquals(
            {'status': 200, 'text': "hello world"},
            {'status': r.status_code, 'text': r.text},
        )
```

There is a decent reason why what you requested isn't allowed.  If your tests could continue after a failed assertion, there's a good chance you'd hit a less explicit error down the line because the environment is in an unexpected state.  Consider:

```
class TestContinuesOnAssert(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rest_api_foo(self):
        """Imagine this continues on assert"""
        r = request("http://dummyurl")
        self.assertIsNotNone(r)
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(r.text, "hello world")
```

With the normal behavior, if for some reason `r` is `None` your code exits early with a helpful message: `AssertionError: unexpectedly None`.  Without it, your code would get the following more opaque exception: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'`.